# How to bind @RequestParam to object in spring MVC?

Tags: java, json, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I want to make a POST request through AJAX, and I also want to bind the whole class object to the request, and I want to receive that request with `@requestParam` annotation. I know it can be done with `@requestBody` annotation, but I am curious to know: can we do it with `@requestParam` annotation?

An Ajax code:

```
var restDTO{
    id: 3,
    name: "hello"
}

 $.ajax({
          url: url, 
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json',
          contentType: 'application/json',
          mimeType: 'application/json',
          data: JSON.stringify({RestDTO : restDTO}),          
          success: function(data) 
    {
    }
```

I do have RestDTO

```
Class RestDTO 
{

    int id;
    String name;

    //getter and setter

}
```

In controller

```
public String content(@RequestParam RestDTO restDTO){...}
```

What should I do the make this code run?

What should I change in sending data from ajax?

Do I need to change on server to receive an RestDto object with `@requestParam` annotation?

Answer (score 19):

You can't, because `@RequestParam` just indicates, that *one* method's parameter should be bound to a *one* web request's parameter. It can't do mapping to objects. For use `@RequestParam` you should change ajax request:

```
var restDTO{
   id: 3,
   name: "hello"
}

 $.ajax({
          url: url, 
          type: 'POST',
          data: restDTO,          
          success: function(data){
             ....
          }
});
```

JQuery will send request as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and will process data to parameters automatically. You controller's method should look like following:

```
@RequestMapping("/url")
public String content(@RequestParam Long id, @RequestParam String name){...}
```

For automatically map parameters to object you can use `@ModelAttribute` annotation:

```
@RequestMapping("/url")
public String content(@ModelAttribute RestDTO restDTO){...}
```

In this case, names in javascript map should match to names of properties in `RestDTO`.

Generally, `@ModelAttribute` and `@RequestBody` created for same purposes: for binding data from request to method (whether objects of primitive type).

I consider, that `@ModelAttribute` is more convenient, when you working with html-forms and plain objects. There is ready to use Spring abilities like `modelAttribute` and `path`.

In its turn, `@RequestBody` more flexible, when you need manual control over data. Also, it is more convenient, when you're working with complex objects.

Personally me would prefer `@RequestBody` and json.

Comment: Thanks for your description, I tried it and i got to know:
1. RequestBody + json.
2. ModelAttribute + application/x-www-form-urlencoded

but in the end, i could not found any difference from it... I mean where to use when ??
javascript map should match to names of properties in both case

Comment: @user3029929 You're right, this approaches need for same things. But, in my point of view, `ModelAttribute` very useful only when you working with web-forms, in other cases `RequestBody` more convenient.

Comment: `@ModelAttribute` takes an object from or adds an object to the model. It has nothing to do with binding whatsoever.

Comment: @zeroflagL, hmmm. Did you ever read this documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args ? Can you explain me, what does next phrase mean:  `...Once present in the model, the argument’s fields should be populated from all request parameters that have matching names. This is known as data binding in Spring MVC...`? Don't you know why, according to this doc `BindingResult` should stay right after `@ModelAttribute` param? It would be curious to see your explanation.

Comment: Binding happens with or without `@ModelAttribute`. That's the default behavior for posted forms. You deliberately omitted the relevant part of the documentation, the two sentences before: _"An @ModelAttribute on a method argument indicates the argument should be retrieved from the model. If not present in the model, the argument should be instantiated first and then added to the model."_. This, and only this, is the purpose of `@ModelAttribute`.

Answer (score 10):

If you're sending your data as classic request params, you can bind to object by simply omitting the `@RequestParam`, so

```
public String content(RestDTO restDTO){...}
```

If you're sending `json`, you have to use `@RequestBody`.

If whysoever you're insisting on the [`@RequestParam`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html), note that you can bind multiple values against a map, so

```
public String content(@RequestParam Map<String, String> restDTO){...}
```

From the [`@RequestParam`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) doc

> If the method parameter is Map or
>   MultiValueMap and a parameter name is not specified,
>   then the map parameter is populated with all request parameter names
>   and values.

Comment: it always give NULL values of properties (id, name) in RestDTO

Comment: sorry, missed one point. if you're sending data as json, you have to use `@RequestBody`

Comment: is there any way in which I can receive data with @requestParam in an class object ??

however on ajax side, I can choose anyway

Comment: You can bind to a map, I've added it to the answer

Answer (score 6):

In spring web you have these annotations:

RequestParam - used for get params (/path?name=)

PathVariable - used for path params (/path/{name})

RequestBody - used for post/put/patch etc. body

RequestHeader - for headers

So you can't use RequestParam for post params, doesn't matter if json or not