# Spring ReST controller: how to avoid methods with same RequestParams

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In a Spring ReST Controller class, there are three methods with identical @RequestParams, but different RequestMappings and behavior, like in the following (simplified) example:

```
@RequestMapping(method = GET, value = "/search")
    public MySearchResponse findAll(
            @RequestParam(required = false, value = "foo") String foo,
            @RequestParam(required = false, value = "bar") String bar,
            @RequestParam(required = false, value = "baz") Long baz,
            @RequestParam(required = false, value = "fooBar") Long fooBar
    ) { ...}

@RequestMapping(method = GET, value = "/export")
    public MyExportResponse exportAll(
            @RequestParam(required = false, value = "foo") String foo,
            @RequestParam(required = false, value = "bar") String bar,
            @RequestParam(required = false, value = "baz") Long baz,
            @RequestParam(required = false, value = "fooBar") Long fooBar
    ) { ...}
```

Is there a way to avoid code duplication concerning the @RequestParam's?

Comment: Use an object to bind to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace them with a single object.

```
static class MyParmeters {
    String foo;
    String bar;
    Long baz;
    Long fooBar;
}

@RequestMapping(method = GET, value = "/search")
public MySearchResponse findAll(MyParmeters params) { ... }

@RequestMapping(method = GET, value = "/export")
public MyExportResponse exportAll(MyParameters params) { ... }
```

See also [How to bind `@RequestParam` to object in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36003481/476716).

Comment: That seems to be quite a nice solution :-) Is there a way to conveniently check if the `required`-Constraint is fulfilled (in case there are `@RequestParams` with attribute `required=true`)

Comment: [Spring MVC: How to perform validation?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12146298/476716)

Answer (score 0):

You can define parent type called `MyResponse` and then you can use `ResponseEntity` as shown below:

```
@RequestMapping(method = GET, value = "/searchOrExport")
public ResponseEntity<MyResponse> exportAll(@RequestParam(required = false, value = "foo") String foo,
            @RequestParam(required = false, value = "bar") String bar,
            @RequestParam(required = false, value = "baz") Long baz,
            @RequestParam(required = false, value = "fooBar") Long fooBar) {
      //code to handle search and Export
}
```

**Bean class API shown below:**

```
public abstract class MyResponse  {
    //any common properties add here
}


public class MySearchResponse implements MyResponse {
   //add MySearchResponse properties
}

public class MyExportResponse implements MyResponse {
   //add MyExportResponse properties
}
```